# How to add Spark to Maven project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spark-java

I would like to start [Spark](http://www.sparkjava.com/) project in Eclipse using Maven.
I've installed m2eclipse and I have a working HelloWorld Java application in my Maven project.

I would like to use Spark framework and I'm following directions from [the official site](http://www.sparkjava.com/download.html).
I've added Spark repository to my `pom.xml`:

```
<repository>
      <id>Spark repository</id>
      <url>http://www.sparkjava.com/nexus/content/repositories/spark/</url>
</repository>
```

And then the dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.9.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

But I'm getting an error in Eclipse:

```
Missing artifact spark:spark:jar:0.9.9.4-SNAPSHOT
```

How can I resolve this issue? I don't want to download Spark's jar file and place in the local repository.

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spark1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Spark1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repository>
      <id>Spark repository</id>
      <url>http://www.sparkjava.com/nexus/content/repositories/spark/</url>
  </repository>

  <dependencies>
<!--     (...) -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.9.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Could you show us your whole `pom.xml`? You can omitt other dependencies but I'd like to see the structure. Also make sure your Eclipse project really has Maven enabled (rigt click on project=>`Configure`=>`Convert to Maven Project`).

Comment: @André I've added pom.xml file to description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `repository` block needs to be wrapped in a `repositories` block:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Spark repository</id>
        <url>http://www.sparkjava.com/nexus/content/repositories/spark/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 12):

Currently no repository is required to add for Spark library loading

You just need to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And that's it.

Useful tutorials to play with is [here](http://sparkjava.com/tutorials/)

Answer (score 5):

Reason for failure is 0.9.9.4-SNAPSHOT is not available.Below is the list of the snapshots available. Use one among them based on your requirement.

0.9.8-SNAPSHOT/     Sat May 21 21:54:23 UTC 2011
0.9.9-SNAPSHOT/     Mon May 23 10:57:38 UTC 2011
0.9.9.1-SNAPSHOT/   Thu May 26 09:47:03 UTC 2011
0.9.9.3-SNAPSHOT/   Thu Sep 01 07:53:59 UTC 2011

Thanks,
Sankara Reddy

Answer (score 0):

I had run into same issue because initially I started with different repository url for spark and then to use earlier version I changed the repository url. Some how it didn't seem to come into effect until I changed the repository id. Try changing the repository id. 

Could be bug in maven because running maven from console also couldn't resolve the dependency without updating the id.

Comment: This actually worked for me.. all I did was I changed id from "Spark repository" to "Spark Repository".

Answer (score 0):

please add the repository , tag inside the repositories tag like below

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Spark repository</id>
            <url>http://www.sparkjava.com/nexus/content/repositories/spark/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

The last versions (2.1 and later) of Spark only need the dependency defined inside the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

the repository definition is not longer required

Answer (score 0):

use this latest repository.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/1.6.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this, and also make sure you change spark library to version 2.11.x in eclipse project build path

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.spark-scala</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-scala</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>Spark in Scala</description>
    <inceptionYear>2010</inceptionYear>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.tools.version>2.10</scala.tools.version>
        <!-- Put the Scala version of the cluster -->
        <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- repository to add org.apache.spark -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera-repo-releases</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- "package" command plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```